# ? operator shows an "unreachable code detected" warning

Tags: c#, operators

I'm implementing an equals method and one of the equality conditions is that two dates match. My current code is:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null || obj.GetType() != typeof(Appointment))
        return false;
    Appointment other = obj as Appointment;
    bool equal = true;
    equal = (this.date == null ? (other.date == null) : (this.date.Equals(other.date)));
    //more stuff here
    return equal
}
```

when I try to build this, I get a warning pointing to the other.date==null statement saying unreachable code detected

however when I replace it with this:

```
if (this.date == null)
    equal = other.date == null;
else
    equal = (this.date.Equals(other.date));
```

I get no such warning

what am I missing?

Comment: What type is `date`? Show us your object declaration.

Comment: If this is instance var, maybe you change it somewhere before this code, don't you?

Comment: Is `date` a non-nullable struct, like `DateTime`? If so, it will *never* be null, that's what the compiler is telling you.

Comment: yes it seems the problem was that I didn't declare date as DateTime? and instead forgot to add the ? . WHen I changed that it didn't throw any more warnings, what I find peculiar though is that even though date was originally declared as DateTime , the second code did not throw a warning

Answer (score 0):

I don't get such warning when the datatype is "object", but I get it as soon as I changed the datatype to "DateTime". So it has to do with the datatype. Datetime can't be null. Anyway you should check if "other" is null:

```
Appointment other = obj as Appointment;
bool equal = false;  // init to false is better
if (other != null)
{
    equal = (this.date == null ? (other.date == null) : (this.date.Equals(other.date)));
}
return equal;
```

Comment: `other` cannot be null (I think) because of the `obj.GetType() != typeof(Appointment)` early.